# Move Tomb Raider save files from Steam to Epic

Tags: steam, tomb-raider-2013, epic-games-launcher

I am playing Tomb Raider on Steam. Yesterday I claimed a free copy of Tomb Raider GOTY on Epic. Is there a way to move save files from Steam to Epic (I would like to try the GOTY features)? I moved the save files to a correct directory (`%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Tomb Raider\[some guid]`) but the game says they're corrupted. Any suggestions?

Comment: Theoretically, there's a lot of DLC + Survival Mode, and if the Steam version has none that should or some data that can't exist in the Epic version that could be an issue. Are they the same exact version other than GOTY + regular editions?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: No. And since GOTY gives actually nothing important, I didn't care anymore.